# CS0426 When Adding a WCF Service Reference

Tags: visual-studio, wcf

I have 3 projects in the same solution - one exposes a WCF service and the other two consume the service.  One of the consumers works fine, but the other generates a CS0426 on the generated Reference.cs saying that  isn't a member of my namespace.  Adding the service reference works fine (no errors), this only happens on build.

So far, I cannot find a difference between the two projects...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a [blog post](http://bursjootech.blogspot.com/2008/06/wcf-type-name-servicereference1-does.html) that solved it for me.  The short answer is that it was because I had a namespace and class with the same name in the consumer.  Weird that it causes this error though...  I couldn't really see why.

Comment: oh yeah, that makes sense. `using WCFService` and a class `WCFService` might cause that. Glad it is resolved.

Comment: For a long-winded explanation to this problem, see: [Eric Lippert's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/namespaces/)

Comment: It seems as though this would be an easy thing to a) give a better message or b) generate a compiler warning...